# sed substitution of a character at the beginning of each line

Tags: unix, sed

The task is to:

Using the sed command substitute for the "." in the first column with an uppercase "Z".

The commands that I have been using are:

```
sed 's/^./Z/' t1 >> t2
```

All that I seem to get is a Z in front of every line not just the ".". It is weird cause it seemed to work on my other commands. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in regular expression speak, `.` means any character. To match a literal `.` character, you need to escape it, like `\.`. So use

```
 sed '/^\./Z/' t1 >> t2
```

IHTH